# R question. Unexplainably empty factor combinations when plotting response

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

I am using the ex0622 data from library Sleuth2

```
library(Sleuth2)

library(lattice)

attach(ex0622)

#Using the 'rep()' function to create a vector for the sexual preference variable ('Hetero' or 'Homo')
sex.pref=as.factor(c(rep("Hetero", 16), rep("Homo", 19), rep("Hetero", 6)))


#Using the 'rep()' function to create a vector for the Type of Death variable ('AIDS' or 'Non-AIDS')

death.type=c(rep("Aids",6), rep("Non-Aids",10), rep("Aids", 19), "Aids", rep("Non-Aids", 5))

#creating a vector of gender variable
gender=(c(rep("Male", 35), rep("Female", 6)))

length(death.type)

ex0622_alt=as.data.frame(cbind(ex0622, gender, sex.pref, death.type))
ex0622_alt
```

I run the preceeding code to add some factors to the data set. Then I want to display certain combinations of variables with the lattice package

```
histogram(~Volume[sex.pref=="Hetero"]|gender, data=ex0622_alt, main="Heterosexuals")
dotplot(Volume[sex.pref=="Hetero"]~gender,  col=1)
```

Both those attempts produce empty combinations of the factors gender and sex.pref when they should not. I have no idea what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Taking a quick look through the data I see no subject with both `gender=="female"` and `sex.pref=="homo"`, so you would expect empty combinations right?

Comment: True, but he is subsetting on `sex.pref == "Hetero"`, and there are both Male and Female cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the `histogram` call: Within the `ex0622_alt` data-frame, you're subsetting the `Volume` variable by `sex.pref == "Hetero"`, but you're *not* subsetting the `gender` variable at all, so the `Volume` subvector and the `gender` variable don't have the same length, so results will be strange. It works if you do:

```
histogram(~Volume[sex.pref=="Hetero"] | 
           gender[sex.pref=='Hetero'], data=ex0622_alt, main="Heterosexuals")
```

Or you could just use the `subset` arg, which would be more natural:

```
histogram(~Volume | gender, 
          data = ex0622_alt, subset = sex.pref == 'Hetero', main="Heterosexuals")
```

Same comment (and fix) applies to the `dotplot` command.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly and was very helpful. "subset" is a wonderful command!